# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm creating a program wherein the user will login into the system, but it gets an error like this,

Also I'm using c# programming language and Ms Access from my database.

this is my whole code.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Shakeys_Inventory_System
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();

        public frmLogin()
        {
            //SplashScreen
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashStart));
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            InitializeComponent();

            this.BackColor = Color.White;
            panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(25, Color.Black);

            t.Abort();

            cn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C: \Users\Raphael\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Shakeys_Inventory_System\Shakeys_Inventory_System\ShakeysDatabase.accdb");
        }

        //Blurred Panel *START
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        }

        public void SplashStart()
        {
            Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
        }

        public void DrawPath(Pen pen, GraphicsPath path)
        { 

        }

        private void frmLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //Button Login Start
        private void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand();
            cm.Connection = cn;
            cm.CommandText = "Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = '" +txt_Username.Text+ "' and password = '"+txt_Password.Text+"'";
            OleDbDataReader odr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            int cnt = 0;
            while (odr.Read())
            {
                cnt++;
            }
            if (cnt == 1)
            {
                this.Hide();
                frmHomepage fhp = new frmHomepage("Welcome:"+ txt_Username.Text);
                fhp.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is Incorrect!", "ERROR!",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
            cn.Close();
        }

        //Button Quit *Start
        private void btn_Quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult Result1 = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to CLOSE the program?", "Warning!",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if (Result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I created my own Database in MSACESS and copy the path file in it and pase into my,

```
cn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C: \Users\Raphael\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Shakeys_Inventory_System\Shakeys_Inventory_System\ShakeysDatabase.accdb");
```

The path file is right, and my query is also right, the table also, my problem is, why am I getting an error?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which line does the code throw the error?

Comment: *why am I getting an error?*, simply giving the exception type is not enough.  You need to provide the message for the exception and preferably the stack trace.  (The same goes for any inner exception on the thrown exception).

Comment: WIDE-OPEN TO SQL INJECTION.  Parameterize your queries.

Comment: Sir Nex Terren, in the line of cn.Open(); in the code of my btn_login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

? character is a place-holder for where you want parameter

```
cm.CommandText = "Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = ? and password = ?";
```

Now, add your parameters in the same order as the query is written

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmUserName", txt_Username.Text );
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmPassword", txt_Password.Text );
```

Now execute your query

```
OleDbDataReader odr = cm.ExecuteReader();
```

If someone were to include a ' character in the text, it would pre-close the quoted concatenation and throw the rest off causing an error.

Also, your path has an extra space "C: \"  instead of "C:\"

**FEEDBACK**

Clarification on "?".  If you concatenate a string to build a query, you are WIDE-OPEN to sql-injection.  The "?" (literally the ? character) acts as a place-holder meaning. I am going to supply "parameters" to the query command, and I want you to put the first parameter where the first "?" is located, and the second parameter at the second "?".

So, lets take a look at your original query

```
"Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = '" +txt_Username.Text+ "' and password = '"+txt_Password.Text+"'";
```

and lets say I entered the following values for

```
txt_Username.Text = "O'Brien"
txt_Password.Text = "it's ok"
```

Your resulting sql command would actually become

```
Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = 'O'Brien' and password = 'it's ok'
```

Notice the mis-matched quote balances around the user and password VALUES.

By using the "?" as the place-holder

```
Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = ? and password = ?

cm.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmUserName", txt_Username.Text );
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmPassword", txt_Password.Text );
```

will become

```
Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = [value of first parameter] and password = [value of second parameter]
```

The engine will recognize the data type of string, numeric, date, etc and handle it for you.  You can get more explicit on declaring the TYPE of parameter, but it will typically detect the type for you.

Now, for SQL-Injection, and am not positive about exposure via access, but typically a ";" semi-colon indicates the end of one sql-statement and allow another.  And someone has figured out the name of your tables.  In SQL, double dash is considered a comment follows and ignore it.  Again, this is just a SAMPLE.  Your query constructed with building the string

```
Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = 'O'Brien' and password = 'it's ok'
```

and values of txtUser_Name.Text = "' OR 1=1; truncate table YourTable; --"

The resulting query would look like
    Select * from UsernameInfo where Username = '' OR 1=1; truncate table YourTable; --' and password = 'it's ok'

You would actually execute the first statement which would return all rows via the "OR 1=1" which is always true, then the next statement would delete all records from a "YourTable" which may be part of your database.  Finally, the 'and password portion would be completely ignored because it was commented via --.

Make more sense?

Comment: @raphaelmendoza, see revised answer for clarification on parameters and sql-injection.